# Matplotlib - wider space between dates

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, width, axis-labels

I have a plot with dates as x axis. But I have a lot of space left and right and I would like to get wider space between each of dates that it fill the entire space (width). Now it looks like this:

[image]

My code is:

```
ticks = np.arange(0, len(year_month), 1)
labels = year_month

mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.state('zoomed')  #works fine on Windows

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.xticks(ticks, labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.ylabel('Sentiment')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: @flebool you can post your comment as the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `plt.xlim(xm,xM)` with `xm` and `xM` being your oldest and newest date respectively.